# Hashing Function Vs Loop search

Tags: language-agnostic, hashtable, performance

I have an array of structures, ~100 unique elements, and the structure is not large. Due to legacy code, to find an element in this array i use a hash function to find a likely starting point to start looping from until i find the element i want.

My question is this: Is the hash function (and resulting hash table) overkill ?

I know for large tables hashing is essential for good response time, but for a table *this* size ?

More succinctly, is there a table size below which writing a hash function is unnecessary ?

Language agnostic answers please.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?  PS:  Making code simpler with little or no performance penalty is a very good thing.

Comment: I would measure it, but that requires a r-n-d budget, which i am trying to get. Chicken meet egg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash lookup trades better scalability for a bigger up-front computation cost.  There is no inherent table size, as it depends on the cost of your hash function.  Roughly speaking, if calculating your hash function has the same cost as one hundred equality comparisons, then you could only theoretically benefit from the hash map at some point above one hundred items.  The only way to get specific answers for your case is to measure the performance.

My guess though, is that a hash map for 100 items for performance reasons is overkill.

Comment: There is also the method of storing the hashvalue for an alement *in its table-entry*. That reduces the execution cost to 1 hashfunction call per lookup, at the expense of some memory, of course. Lowering the switchover-point to 5..10 elements.

Comment: It also depends on the key being used when searching.  If the key is an int, lookups will be much faster than if the key is a string or a composite value.

Comment: @SteveWellens:  That was exactly my point.  A hash function is more expensive to compute on a string than an int.

Comment: That is a false argument: a string function (such as strcmp()) is *also* more expensive. The expected function call cost for linear search is 1/2 N, for a reasonable hash-table 2. (one for the hashfunction plus one for the final strcmp()).

Comment: @wildplasser:  I'm not sure what you're saying is a false argument, but I agree with everything you just said.

Comment: The argument is false because you need the string function either way. (assuming that the cost of applying a hashfunction to a string is comparable to the cost of strcmp())

Comment: @wildplasser:  Understood.  That's not an unreasonable assumption, but it's not one I made.  I may have been more general than necessary.

Comment: This is the best explanation of the tipping point. Accepted as such pending actual measurement.

Answer (score 1):

The standard, obvious answer would be/is to write the simplest code that can do the job. Ensure that your interface to that code is as clean as possible so you can replace it when/if needed. Later, if you find that code takes an unacceptable amount of time, replace it with something that improves performance.

On a theoretical basis, however, it's impossible to guess at the upper limit on the number of items for which a linear search will provide acceptable performance for your task. It's also impossible to guess at the number of items for which a hash table will provide better performance than a linear search.

The main point, however, is that it's rarely necessary to try to figure out (especially on a poorly-defined theoretical basis) what data structure would be *best* for a given situation. In most cases, you just need to make an *acceptable* decision, and implement it so you can change your mind later if it turns out to be unacceptable after all.

Answer (score 1):

When creating (or after it's created) sort your 'array of unique elements' by their 'key value'. Then use 'binary search' rather than hash or linear search. Now you get a simple implementation, no extra memory usage and good performance.